# Converting multiple RTP Streams into gRPC Stream

Tags: java, ffmpeg, gstreamer, grpc, rtp

I am receiving multiple RTP streams(g711 ulaw/alaw) which may be coming on TCP or UDP, I want to terminate the RTP and get the raw media from the RTP stream and stream it to a different destination by using Google gRPC protocol.

Currently I have a RTP processing engine which does this and give me the raw stream from RTP stack which i further stream to gRPC destination, but this solution does not scale beyond 1000 streams on one host and is difficult to maintain.

I want to replace this with some highly scalable solution where i can scale to several thousand of streams and does not need to be maintained.

I am exploring option to Use ffmpeg / gstreamer for getting raw packets from RTP stream. Not sure how scalable it would be and how do i get hold of the stream so that i can stream it over gRPC.

I have following questions:

1. Is this good option to use ffmpeg / gstreamer for this purpose.
2. How do i work with multiple streams any suggestions or sample.
3. Any details about the scalability of ffmpeg / gstreamer.
4. I plan to use Java for my application, which java wrapper would be good e.g. Xuggle / ffmpeg-cli-wrapper for ffmpeg.